# Android Production Debug issue

Tags: android

My production build APK prints all the console logs when I use below command,

`adb logcat chromium:I *:S --print`

But I have `debuggable = false` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you running in debug mode or release mode?

Comment: release mode only